# Input text validation when is empty

Tags: validation, oracle-adf

I have three dependent text boxes. That is, department, class and subclass. When the department fill the class of inputText is enable and when preecho the class to subclass is enable. To make this process not had difficulties. However, I can not make the reverse process that is when I delete, for example, the value of the department should put disable the class and delete its value.
I could not do this because it is by events, when it is empty does not trigger a new event and therefore does not enter my else the if.
All text boxes have autosuggest behavior and the class depends on the chosen department and the subclass of the class.
For the class and the subclass have associated partialtriggers.

My code of input text department is that (with valuechangelistener setdepartment()):

```
 public void setDepartment(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {

        DCIteratorBinding dc2 = (DCIteratorBinding)evaluteEL("#{bindings.ScpClassView1Iterator}");
        ViewObject vo2 = dc2.getViewObject();
        vo2.applyViewCriteria(vo2.getViewCriteriaManager().getViewCriteria("ScpClassViewCriteria"));
        if (it7.getValue() == null) {
            vo2.ensureVariableManager().setVariableValue("P_Dept", null);
        } else {
            String deptIdDesc = valueChangeEvent.getNewValue().toString();
            int indexOfSeparator = deptIdDesc.indexOf("-");
            String deptId = deptIdDesc.substring(0, indexOfSeparator - 1);
            vo2.ensureVariableManager().setVariableValue("P_Dept", deptId);
        }
        vo2.executeQuery();
        if (valueChangeEvent.getNewValue().toString().isEmpty()) {
            getIt8().setDisabled(true);
        }  else {
            getIt8().setDisabled(false);
        }
```

Comment: provide us the source code for better solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to run your code in debug mode and set a breakpoint inside setDepartment method? It will confirm whether setDepartment method is invoked on clearing off data from department input. Also, looking at your code, I feel it will throw exception when input is empty.
 `if (it7.getValue() == null)` will evaluate to false when you clear off data, it7 will have blank value instead. Here you need to use `if (valueChangeEvent.getNewValue().toString().isEmpty())`

Comment: Amishra, i use this if (it7.getValue() == null || it7.getValue().equals("") || it7.getValue().toString().isEmpty()) and work's. Thank u so much. Was very important for me.

Comment: Then approve the answer ;)